# Index was outside the bounds of the array. wcf Service in c#

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

In My WCF Service below is the code

```
request.InputStream = httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream;
```

this is what i get data from IOS And Android in body

working fine in IPhone,
but having problem in Android

the error is below.

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I Imagine `httpRequest.Files` is an Empty array. We will need more information if you want help.

Comment: ok, what kind of information you want?

Comment: what are you expecting Files to be? how are you sending your Files.

Comment: Thanks alax no need for that found the solution.